# Android Camera Hardware Information

Tags: android

While we can get physical manufacturer information programmatically through `android.os.*` components, I haven't seen references to checking in on the camera details.

Specifically, I was curious if there was a way to detect what camera sensor was being used in a specific device so that adjustments could be made as necessary?  With some Samsung Galaxy S6 devices having different camera sensors found in them sporadically, I can't rely on just the device itself and it would be best if I did it based on the physical hardware for the camera.

reference: [Camera Sensor Discrepencies](http://www.sammobile.com/2015/05/05/heres-the-difference-between-samsung-and-sony-camera-sensors-on-the-galaxy-s6-and-s6-edge/)

This is in reference of course to correcting and detecting the appearance of colors properly within an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an Android App there are many in market now. [Camera2 API probe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbeat.device.inspector&hl=en_SG) is one of the best (I have no affiliations with this, but I use this in my work).

Alternatively you can very easily probe information using Camera2 APIs like:

1. [CameraCharacteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics?hl=en)
2. [CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics?hl=en#CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES) - for AE modes
3. [CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics?hl=en#CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES) - for AF modes

And more available on Android documentation - just look for Camera2

Comment: I wasn't referencing information such as that, but about the physical hardware that is being used.  Such as what the specific image sensor is that they use on the device that they connect wires to on the chip.

Comment: I see. From camera characteristics level I see only INFO_VERSION is available that too was added in API 28, that could give some sense on hardware manufacturer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#INFO_VERSION

Comment: Sadly, INFO_VERSION is optional and gives null on my camera :(

Answer (score -1):

[This video explains how to get camera hardware info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDXMTrL3VH0).

You need to have a root access in your android phone. Use Esfile explorer and search "camera_info". You will get a file depending upon the android phone, that when you open, will get your camera hardware info.